# The same plugin in two *.jar files

Tags: neo4j

I have the same plugin in two *.jar files (for example: `my-plugin-1.0.jar` and `my-plugin-1.1.jar`). Can neo4j get warning or error in this case?

TIA.

CLOSED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create some script into plugin than check files by mask.